# What is the description of a group?

Tags: group-theory, cryptography

I am currently reading a paper on verifiable delay functions and when talking about the security of Pietrzak's succinct argument the description of a group is mentioned:

> Let $\operatorname{GGen}(\lambda)$ be a randomized algorithm that outputs the description of a group $\mathbb{G}$ of unknown order.

What does it mean by "description of a group"? (I know what "a group" is, I just do not understand the output of this function $\operatorname{GGen}(\lambda)$.)

Here is the paper: Page 5 chapter 3.1
http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/VDFsurvey.pdf

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)

Comment: What do you mean by "that"? Do you mean "the description of a group" (as in the title of the question), or "a group" (as @Servaes is suggesting)?

Comment: I mean the description of a group, I have good basics in group theory and I have never heard of the description of a group

Comment: Do you know the definition of a group?

Comment: Among mathematicians, the phrase "description of a group" is devoid of any concrete meaning. One would need to specify what it means in a specific context. (For example, it might mean producing a representative from the isomorphism class that the group belongs to, or it could mean exhibiting a Cayley table for the group, or something similar.) You'll need to guess what the author means at that point. If you can't, it'd be best to contact the author(s) and ask.

Comment: I think they just mean "some description", in an informal sense. For example, in section 6 they say "let $\operatorname{GGen}$ be an algorithm that outputs an odd integer $N$ with an unknown factorization", and the authors interpret this integer as a description of the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$. ($\operatorname{GGen}$ is their function which outputs a "description" of a group.)

Comment: I don't understand why this question is "missing context or other details". It is clear what the question is, and has been verified in the comments. "Question: I came across this weird thing in a paper. What does it mean? Here is a link to the question." What more context do you need?!?

Comment: "Description" doesn't mean anything, but from the context it's referring to identifying the group in question up to isomorphism. The data used to do so could be, for example, a presentation, but the point is just that the group is uniquely identified.